# How many people still use JRE 1.5 or older?

Tags: java

Is there some statistic on how widely people use various JRE's? I'm asking, because I created a program (using JDK 1.6), and found that it would not work on JRE 1.5 and older. So, do I need to bother making it compatible, or maybe the percent of JRE 1.5 out there is too small?

Comment: How will a straw-poll of SO users help you decide this?

Comment: You can do a simple web search of 'java version statistics' to get answers to this question.

Comment: Also ask yourself, "Who are my customers? Which JDK will they typically be running?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some stats:

- http://www.statowl.com/java.php

Don't really know how it's calculated... I think come from users browser, but don't know which websites.

Comment: It’s *number of browsers, that have Java enabled* divided by *number of all browsers*. So it has nothing to do with what Java version is used.

Comment: Down the page, there is a pie charts of java versions.

Comment: There don't appear to be any results at that page any more.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have your JDK emit bytecode for older JVMs with the [`-target SDK_VERSION`](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/how_to_cross_compile_for) argument to `javac`. Bytecode from one version of the JVM is not compatible with an older release of the JVM.

**Thanks to comment**

The above only works if you are not using functionality that older JVMs don't have, for example, if you took advantage of the Java Desktop API, which was introduced in 1.6, you wouldn't be able to target an older JVM anyway.

I won't throw statistics your way, I don't really know what your application is/does/who it's intended for, but there are companies and people who still use older JDKs - perhaps due to heavy investment in some specific release of the JVM and it would require significant time and testing to ensure that moving to a newer version does not break their existing software/code, or perhaps some software strictly mandates it. I worked with software from a company (which shall remain unnamed) that ONLY wanted a specific patch revision of an older JVM - their software refused to work on anything newer.

Comment: Presumably, he uses functions/classes that don't exist in 1.5, so `-target` (which I presume is what you meant) won't work.

Comment: @R. Bemrose - thanks for the comment, I updated to reflect the concerns your brought up.

Answer (score 2):

Um yes *plenty* of enterprises use earlier versions of Java.  You simply need to decide what your lowest level target JVM is.  Don't forget you can use the -source & -target parameters to specify the type of source code and byte code compatibility with earlier versions.

Comment: yep, in late 2008 at least some banks were still very much with 1.4.

Comment: Heck in late 2010 several do, I know I have to deal with at least one of them :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any statistics, but for what is worth I am certain people use Java 1.5. If your app is geared toward general public, I don't think you need to bother, but in specialized environments it might be.

Answer (score 1):

If your application will be for consumers, you will probably be fine relying on 1.6.

Most places that are still running 1.5 are for business applications that have not been updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using any Java 1.6 specific features, you can pass a command line argument to javac to target the 1.5 framework.  The argument to add is `-target 1.5`. Obviously this wouldn't work if you're using any new features shipped with 1.6.